# Php calculate method

Tags: php

What I'm trying to figure out in php is how to make something like
125x2.5=312
And take the answer and do this:
312x2.5
So basicly take the last answer and calculate it.
I would like to do this with a while loop.

The answer needs to be done * (times) 2.5 of the pervious answer.

Please help, I'm a noob in php.
Little question for big problem :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a maths problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @vascowhite I would say that the OP doesn't know the rudimentary basics of variables, how to use them or assign values to them. We were all there at one point.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value you get to a variable - and display that variable at the same time as changing its value:

```
<?php

    $var=125;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
        $var=$var*2.5;
        echo floor($var).'<br>';
    }

?>
```

I rounded it down to output nice round values like this:

```
312
781
1953
4882
12207
```

This will output your values 5 times.

As you edited your question however and want it in a while loop, you can use the following:

```
<?php

    $var=125;
    while($var<100000)
    {
        $var=$var*2.5;
        echo floor($var).'<br>';
    }

?>
```

Which has the following output:

```
312
781
1953
4882
12207
30517
76293
190734
```

Now, what might be interesting is that there is a value output that is *greater* than the test. That is because prior to the while loop, the value was actually lower - so the loop was entered, the value changed and was output - and THEN the next iteration of the loop failed.